# Pixelate effect when converting MOV to FLV via FFMPEG

Tags: final-cut-pro, ffmpeg

I have a .MOV video -created with Final Cut Pro 7 - which I'm converting to .flv using FFMPEG. I'm very happy about the quality and the size of the output file, but whenever I have fade in/out transitions in the input video, I get a pixelate effect on the output file. Any advice on how to solve this, without increase too much the output file size?

```
FRAME_SIZE=720x576
BIT_RATE=1200k

ffmpeg -s $FRAME_SIZE -i $1 -g 250 -ar 44100 -deinterlace -b $BIT_RATE -minrate $BIT_RATE -maxrate $BIT_RATE -bufsize 10000k -qblur 0.3 $2
```

Where $1 and $2 are, respectively, the input and output file.

Comment: Can you post what parameters you are using in ffmpeg? It sounds like a bitrate issue

Comment: @Colum: There you go.

Comment: I think it is an issue with interlacing. Try removing that flag

Comment: @Colum. That didn't help. Actually, it causes horizontal lines to be displayed on the output video.

Answer (score 2):

You should explicitly specify a video codec using `-vcodec` as well as quality settings.

The problem is that `ffmpeg`'s defaults aren't very sensible when you only specify a container format for the output, often choosing a sub-standard video format by default.

If you want H.264 output, try using the [presets](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-doc.html#SEC13), e.g. `-vcodec libx264 -vpre max`. (To see what presets are available, try `ls /usr/share/ffmpeg/*.ffpreset`.)

Answer (score 1):

Try converting the file using [MPEG Streamclip], MPEG Streamclip is a good free file converter. Export the project from Final Cut Pro 7 and use MPEG Streamclip to convert the file.

(http://www.squared5.com/)

Answer (score -2):

Try the `-sameq` option. It tells `ffmpeg` to use the same quality in the output as in the input. I often find that `ffmpeg` likes to use sub-standard video codecs.

Comment: no it doesn't. It tells ffmpeg to use the same Quantizer. Common mistake.

Comment: And there is no `-sameq` option in `ffmpeg/avconv`anymore.